# How to make the question mark inline with the text

Tags: python, css, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

**Code:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import base64
import io
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table

from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

app = dash.Dash(
    __name__, meta_tags=[{"name": "viewport", "content": "width=device-width"}], suppress_callback_exceptions=True
)
server = app.server

app.layout = html.Div(children=[html.Label("Select Model"), html.Abbr("\u2753", title="Hello, I am hover-enabled helpful information.")])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(port=8069, debug=True)#, dev_tools_ui=False,dev_tools_props_check=False)
```

[image]

I am unable to make it inline with this `html.Label` tag. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I just want to create a info hover for the labels/text. This was the solution I found on the community but it gives that hover icon in new line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `float = 'left'` in the `html.Label` style like this:

```
app.layout = html.Div(children=[html.Label("Select Model", style = {'float': 'left'}), html.Abbr("\u2753", title="Hello, I am hover-enabled helpful information.")])
```

[image]